# query won't update, using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My first query is this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE application SET userid = ? WHERE appid = ? LIMIT 1";
```

My second query is this:

```
SELECT user.name,application.appid,application.userid,application.created,application.title,application.filesize,application.status,application.apptype 
FROM user,application 
WHERE application.appid = ? LIMIT 1
```

Then the second query is stored using `$statement->fetchObject()`

The problem is that `$statement->name` is always `bob`. `application.userid` is a foregin key to `userid` in table `user`. If I change the `userid` in table `application`, lets say `10`, query 2 should get the name from the table `user` on the new `userid`, but the problem is that it keeps telling me that `$statement->name` is `bob`.

```
if (isset($_POST['newowner']))
{
    $newowner = $_POST['newowner'];
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user 
            WHERE userid = ? LIMIT 1";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($newowner));

    if ($statement->fetchColumn() > 0)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE application SET userid = ? 
                WHERE appid = ? LIMIT 1";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array($newowner,$_GET['appid']));
        $appdetail->msg = "Owners were successfully changed.";
        $appdetail->type = "success";
    }
    else
    {
        $appdetail->msg = "Could not find client by that userid or email.";
        $appdetail->type = "warning";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT user.name,application.appid,application.userid,application.created,application.title,application.filesize,application.status,application.apptype 
        FROM user,application 
        WHERE application.appid = ? LIMIT 1";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array($_GET['appid']));
$app = $statement->fetchObject();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO you should be able to determine how many rows are affected by the UPDATE. Check that this corresponds to the number of rows you expect to be modified in your test data. Edit: [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) is the statement you'll need.

Comment: Two more possibilities: there is a mistake in your PHP code (can we see it?) or you are operating in a transaction and need to commit first (does your select pick up changes if you modify rows in phpmyadmin?). My guess is it's the first case.

Comment: *Added

The rest of the code is just outputs. No syntax errors.

Comment: I'm starting to thing that my tables were not normalized correctly. It's a pretty basic and standard concept.

Comment: I fixed it. I added the where clause: `application.userid = user.userid`. I'm such a dummy :P Will accept this answer for helping me.

Comment: Hmm. Do you intend for there to be a join between user and application? Also - do you have warnings switched on in your dev environment?

Comment: Heh heh - we both got there in the end. Just seen your last answer ;-)